# $\overline{f(z)}$ has the derivative zero with respect to $z$

Tags: complex-analysis

$\overline{f(z)}$ has the derivative zero with respect to $z$? $z=x+iy$, then $x=1/2(z+\overline{z}), y = -i/2(z-\overline{z})$. $f(z) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$.

By chain rule, do we get
$$\frac{\partial\overline{f(x,y)}}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\partial\overline{f(x,y)}}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial\overline{f(x,y)}}{\partial y} \right) - \frac{i}{2} \left(\frac{\partial\overline{f(x,y)}}{\partial x} +\frac{\partial\overline{f(x,y)}}{\partial y} \right)?$$

Why is $\frac{\partial\overline{f(x,y)}}{\partial z} =0$?

Comment: Are you assuming that $f$ is holomorphic? In other words, Does $f$ satisfy Cauchy-Riemann equations?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Your expression for $\tfrac{\partial}{\partial z}$ doesn't seem to be right.

$x=\tfrac12(z+\bar z)$ and $y=\tfrac1{2i}(z-\bar z)$, so
$\tfrac{\partial x}{\partial z} = \tfrac12$ and $\tfrac{\partial y}{\partial z} = \tfrac1{2i}=-\tfrac{i}{2}$. Then to apply to (say) $g$, we have

$$\tfrac{\partial g}{\partial z} = \tfrac{\partial g}{\partial x}\tfrac{\partial x}{\partial z} + \tfrac{\partial g}{\partial y}\tfrac{\partial y}{\partial z}
=\tfrac12\tfrac{\partial g}{\partial x} - \tfrac{i}{2}\tfrac{\partial g}{\partial y}
=\tfrac12\left(\tfrac{\partial g}{\partial x}-i\tfrac{\partial g}{\partial y}\right)$$
and similarly
$$\tfrac{\partial g}{\partial \bar z} =\tfrac12\left(\tfrac{\partial g}{\partial x}+i\tfrac{\partial g}{\partial y}\right).$$

Now apply this to $g=\bar f$.